# Close frame only if another specific frame is been closed before

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I have a JFrame (mainframe) and JButton put in. When i click on JButton, this open another JFrame.  I want to close mainframe only if the second frame is closed and i want obtain the same effect of when you have a open JChooser and try to close the JFrame. (JChooser flashing if you try to click on the X's frame). How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be easily done with JDialog. Read the below mentioned link.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html